# Combine customer primary keys

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, business-logic, ssis-2012

I have 4 systems gathered in one dwh and it has now come to joining the different customer primary keys. 
One actual customer may be present in all 4 systems or only one of them. 
What would you see as the most preferable solution for doing the business logic lookup? 
The links are week so regular joins will only work for a small part of the customers. 
Is there a good ssis work flow I can use or how would you approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I work for a large health insurance company and we recently had to do a somewhat similar project. We had several source systems that came from different business units which contained member information. We have a large member population and the members may be in multiple systems. Data in the systems was only so so in terms of quality: each system may or may not have valid SSNs, Medicare IDs, current and/or properly spelled address information, valid birth dates, etc. Our goal was to create a unique identifier that we could pair with the source system PKs so that we could uniquely identify a member across many systems.

The result was more of a process than a single piece of code or SSIS task. Our process keeps track of every member that ever comes through our system, as well as a snapshot of the primary fields with which we identify them (name, address, SSN, Medicare ID, etc). On each build, we add new members that haven't come into our system before as well as update the history table. We then go through compares and try to find out which members match. We attempt to do full matches (firstname = firstname, lastname = lastname, ssn = ssn) where possible, but if those matches fail, we have to use a partial matching system. What we typically do is try to match an identifier, such as an SSN or a Medicare ID, with parts of the name and address. If we don't have a valid SSN or Medicare ID, we end up using partial matches on all the fields we have available to us.

The process was a bit of trial and error. After our first release, users found all sorts of instances where the same member had different IDs (our matching logic had missed a valid match), or members that were clearly not the same had the same unique identifier (our match logic produced a bad match). After each release, we typically write code based on the errors we find and that typically fixes almost all of them. We are now to a point where we've matched everything we reliably can.

In your case, I'm guessing you don't have any government issued IDs or SSNs available to you. I'd probably try to straight `JOIN` on the info you have (name, shipping address, billing address, email, credit card numbers, etc). After that, move to partial matches. We use the left 4 characters of all the fields we have in cases where we can't straight up `JOIN`. After that, depending on the quality of your data, you may just have to do some leg work to get the rest of the logic down. I'd try to look at all the customers for which you couldn't find any match and see if any of them have the same email, or similar addresses, or similar names. If so, compare these members and see what is causing the match not to work.

EDIT: If this data is continuing to get updated, keep in mind you'll have to also compare new records to previously identified customers to see if they happen to match a customer already in your system.

Best of luck to you. Our project was a bit of a headache and still isn't completely done, but it's in good shape and we continue to improve it with each run that we do.

Comment: Thank you for a good input, I think your approach is really good. What I have started on is a set of different queries that joins customers from different perspectives from a business point of view. I am tagging the the results from the queries with a validation level score from 1 to 5. Where the score is dependent on how strong the joins are. If I find the same customer relationship on more than one query. The score is updated and I then keep working with the customers with non or low score.

Answer (score 0):

As for the data-warehouse - there is good article by Kimball Group on best-practices for handling this kind of data:

http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/07/design-tip-147-durable-super-natural-keys/